# Task.Factory.StartNew with async lambda and Task.WaitAll

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to use `Task.WaitAll` on a list of tasks.  The thing is the tasks are an async lambda which breaks `Tasks.WaitAll` as it never waits.

Here is an example code block:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    using (dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        var records = await dbContext.Where(r => r.Id = 100).ToListAsync();
        //do long cpu process here...
    }
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
//do more stuff here
```

This doesn't wait because of the async lambda.  So how am I supposed to await I/O operations in my lambda?

Comment: What is the point of starting a task on another thread if the first thing you do after you start it is block on the `Task.WaitAll` call? You will get better performance getting rid of `ToListAsync` and making it just `ToList` and running it synchronously. (or if you do want to use `ToListAsync` then you need to use async all the way up your call stack.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`Task.Factory.StartNew` doesn't recognise `async` delegates as there is no overload that accepts a function returning a `Task`.

This plus other reasons (see [StartNew is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)) is why you should be using `Task.Run` here:

```
tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => ...
```

Comment: This worked... sort of.  Not sure the issue now but I'm getting a task cancelled exception trying to return a string.  Seems like a different issue so I'm going to start a new SO thread.  Thanks.

Comment: Too bad Task.run doesn't give you `TaskCreationOptions`

Comment: `Task.Factory.StartNew(Func<Task> function` seems to be available in .NET Standard 1.6 - one might have to `Unwrap()` the resulting `Task`though :)

Answer (score 37):

> This doesn't wait because of the async lambda. So how am I supposed to
>   await I/O operations in my lambda?

The reason `Task.WaitAll` doesn't wait for the completion of the IO work presented by your async lambda is because `Task.Factory.StartNew` actually returns a `Task<Task>`. Since your list is a `List<Task>` (and `Task<T>` derives from `Task`), you wait on the outer task started by `StartNew`, while **ignoring the inner one** created by the async lambda. This is why they say `Task.Factory.StartNew` is *dangerous* with respect to async.

How could you fix this? You could explicitly call `Task<Task>.Unwrap()` in order to get the inner task:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    using (dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        var records = await dbContext.Where(r => r.Id = 100).ToListAsync();
        //do long cpu process here...
    }
}).Unwrap());
```

Or like others said, you could call `Task.Run` instead:

```
tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => /* lambda */);
```

Also, since you want to be doing things right, you'll want to use `Task.WhenAll`, why is asynchronously waitable, instead of `Task.WaitAll` which synchronously blocks:

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do like this.

```
    void Something()
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        tasks.Add(ReadAsync());
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }

    async Task ReadAsync() {
        using (dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            var records = await dbContext.Where(r => r.Id = 100).ToListAsync();
            //do long cpu process here...
        }
    }
```

Comment: This was almost a good answer. You should not block on `Task.WaitAll` if you are using `async` because you can easily deadlock.

Comment: WaitAll is what Jacob wanted to do according to the question.

Answer (score -4):

you have to use the `Task.ContinueWith` method. Like this

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    using (dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        return dbContext.Where(r => r.Id = 100).ToListAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                var records = t.Result;
                // do long cpu process here...
            });
        }
    }
}
```