# Async method within Task.Factory.StartNew wait all tasks before continuing

Tags: c#, async-await, task, multitasking

I have the following code:

```
public async Task<bool> ExecuteAsync()
{        
    return await someresult;
}


public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{

   var tasks = new List<Task>();

   foreach (var item in someList)
   {

         var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
                    {
                          await ExecuteAsync();
                    });

         tasks.Add(task);
   }


   await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

   // The program execution should stop here and next code should be run when all tasks are completed


}
```

Basically I am in a foreach loop where for each item I start a new Task.

Once all tasks are started I want the code after `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` to be executed once all tasks are completed. Of course all are async therefore I am wondering if this is even possible? Because all are async the execution doesnt stop at Task.WhenAll(tasks) but continue even so not all tasks are completed. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are you using `Task.Factory.StartNew`? Are you stuck on .NET 4.0? If not, use `Task.Run` instead

Comment: Also, `async () => await ExecuteAsync()` makes no sense, you have to use `Task.Run(() => ExecuteAsync)`

Comment: StartNew does not support async lambadas directly. The type of `task` is going to be `Task<Task<bool>>` and the `WhenAll` will not behave as you expect. Use Task.Run or you need to call `.Unwrap()` before you add it to the list.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: My understanding is that you should not run Task.Run within a loop. Am I wrong?

Comment: @user2818430 `Task.Run` is preferred over `Task.Factory.StartNew` for normal situations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Task.Factory.StartNew with async lambda and Task.WaitAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819847/task-factory-startnew-with-async-lambda-and-task-waitall)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why you're wasting thread pools for for each task in the loop, your code could be written as:

```
public  Task<bool> ExecuteAsync()
{
    return  ItReturnsATask();
}

public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{

    var tasks = new List<Task>();

      foreach (var item in someList)
      {
        //ExecuteAsync can be replace by ItReturnsATask if there's no extra processing
            tasks.Add(ExecuteAsync());
      }

     await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Your code misses the point of asynchrony, It creates couple of threads from thread pool, and use them, these threads wasted here. As for your actual question, anything after `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` doesn't get executed before all tasks are finished (assuming we're capturing the current context).

Comment: You are making the dangerous assumption that this code runs on a context-less framework which may or not be true. In WinForms, WPF, Xamarin and WebForms, there are **huge** differences between using Thread Pool Threads and not using them.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto If `ExecuteAsync` is a method that needs to not capture the current synchronization context then it should be written to not use it, rather than simply expecting every caller using it to call it from a context-free thread.  That method using the current sync context when it doesn't need it (and shouldn't use it) would be a bug in said method.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I assumptions are based on these two articles [Task.Run Etiquette and Proper Usage](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html), [Task.Run Etiquette Examples: Don't Use Task.Run in the Implementation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html), Can you give me an article about these huge differences?

Comment: @Servy Yes, it *should* be. But there's the fact that we don't know what `ExecuteAsync` does, nor what happens before or after that call. So while the general advice is correct, I don't think you can make that call so easily (imagine for example that `ExecuteAsync` is from a third-party)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto If the method *isn't* written correctly, and is in fact using the current sync context when it shouldn't be then *that method should be corrected*, rather than using `StartNew` or `Run` to call it here.  Rather than trying to hack around a bug just *fix the bug*, if it even exists (you're just assuming that it does).

Comment: @HamidMosalla You said you based on an article that clearly states "Use `Task.Run` to call CPU-bound methods" (I have read those articles some times, FYI...). I know ask you: do you even know what `ExecuteAsync` does so you can decide for the OP whether using `Task.Run` to run the code is appropriate or not?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto We can make an assumption about it or we cannot, non of them is wrong at this point, I'm still waiting for a resource that explains the **huge** differences across frameworks when it comes to using Task.Run.

Comment: @HamidMosalla What I meant was the difference between using Task.Run and not using it at all - i.e the context switch due to a thread pool thread being run. Will see if I can get you a good link