# Strange output when using SemaphoreSlim to lock the method

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a pretty simple console application to test the feature of SemaphoreSlim .

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim> _locks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim>();
    private static int _counter = 0;
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await IncCountWithDictLock("10"))); ;
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        Console.WriteLine(_counter);
    }

    public static async Task IncCountWithDictLock(string userId)
    {
        _locks.TryAdd(userId, new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1));
        var l = _locks[userId];
        var acuireLockRequire = await l.WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        if (acuireLockRequire)
        {
            _counter++;
            l.Release();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("unable acquire the lock");
        }

    }
}
```

I expect the result of counter is 1000 while it is randomly. Did I miss anything when using the SemaphoreSlim?

Comment: The lambda in the `Task.Factory.StartNew` is actually not being awaited. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819847/task-factory-startnew-with-async-lambda-and-task-waitall. Try calling `Unwrap()` for the `StartNew` and see what happens.

Comment: How about just `tasks.Add(IncCountWithDictLock("10"))`?

Comment: @Clemens interesting. Will it run the `Task` automatically?

Comment: The Task returned from IncCountWithDictLock would be awaited in WhenAll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The lambda in the `Task.Factory.StartNew` is actually not being awaited.
>   See [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819847/task-factory-startnew-with-async-lambda-and-task-waitall)

You may replace the calling method

```csharp
tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await IncCountWithDictLock("10")))
```

with

```csharp
tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => await IncCountWithDictLock("10")));
```